# How to call a function with the opposite boolean to what it was previously called with

Tags: javascript

Right, so I am making an *Agario* extension.

I want it so when you press a button (m) it will call a function (the setShowMass) function with the opposite boolean to what is was called with last time.

```
       document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
        var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if(key == 71){
            window.agar.drawGrid = !window.agar.drawGrid;
        }
        if(key == 77){
         setShowMass(!massShown);
         massShown = !massShown;
        }
    });
```

Comment: And what is the issue? If `drawGrid` is indeed a boolean, what are you getting now?

Comment: Drawgrid is a variable however it is the setShowMass I was on about. Sorry I was so vague, will edit my post now.

Comment: Just store the boolean outside and call opposite of it. like `setShowMass(!boolVar)` where `boolVar` is boolean variable stored outside

Comment: Didn't think of that. Sorry, I am generally new to programming...

Comment: @BikasVaibhav that won't automatically update that boolVar though.

Comment: I know, but I jsut wanted to give him direction to work on and not the solutions. Hence it was a comment and not a reply

Comment: It didn't work, for some reason it didn't work.. I have the variable but it is being stupid. I will update my code to show what didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the result:

```
var oppositebool = true;
document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(key == 71){
        window.agar.drawGrid = !window.agar.drawGrid;
    }
    if(key == 77){
        setShowMass(oppositebool);
        oppositebool = !oppositebool;  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a function that wraps another function and calls that function switching between `true` and `false` every time.

```
const trueFalse = (fn, initial) => {
  return () => {
    fn(initial);
    initial = !initial;
  }
};

const log = (bool) => console.log(bool);
const switchingLog = trueFalse(log, true);

switchingLog(); // true
switchingLog(); // false
switchingLog(); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper function that remembers the last value. For example:

```
function callWithOppositeBoolean(func, startingValue) {
    var bool = !startingValue;
    return function() {
        bool = !bool;
        return func(bool);
    }
}
```

Then you can use this to create a wrapped function that calls the original function, alternating with true and false:

```
var toggleShowMass = callWithOppositeBoolean(showMass, true);

toggleShowMass(); // showMass(true)
toggleShowMass(); // showMass(false)
toggleShowMass(); // showMass(true)
```